# Unable to run node using gradle node plugin

Tags: java, node.js, docker, gradle, gitlab

We’re using the gradle node plugin to build our node project from gradle. The gitlab ci template we chose uses the gradle:alpine docker image. In our job we run the gradle wrapper. The build fails with “env: can’t execute ‘node’: No such file or directory”. It builds fine on our linux dev box.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/builds/myueser/myproj/.gradle/nodejs/node-v10.11.0-linux-x64/bin/node" (in directory "/builds/myueser/myproj"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Here are the pertinent contents from the gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: gradle:alpine

variables:
 GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"
 GIT_STRATEGY: clone

before_script:
 - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
 - export PATH=`pwd`/.gradle/nodejs/node-v10.11.0-linux-x64/bin:$PATH

deploy-ui:
 stage: deploy
 script: ./gradlew --build-cache assemble deploymyprojWeb --debug
 cache:
   key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
   policy: pull
   paths:
     - build
     - .gradle
```

Also, the following is from the build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
  id "com.moowork.node" version "1.2.0"
  id 'com.adarshr.test-logger' version '1.5.0'
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "groovy"

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile(
            'junit:junit:4.12',
            'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15',
            'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4',
            gradleTestKit()
    )
}

node {
    version = '10.11.0'
    download = true
}

npm_install {
    args = ["$project.projectDir/myproj", '--prefix',"$project.projectDir/myproj"]
}

task deploymyprojWeb(type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['run','deploy', '--prefix',"$project.projectDir/myproj"]
}
deploymyprojWeb.dependsOn npm_install

wrapper {
   gradleVersion = '4.10.2' //version required
}
```

Content of node distribution folder (/builds/myuser/myproj/.gradle/nodejs/node-v10.11.0-linux-x64/bin):

```
/builds/myuser/myproj/.gradle/nodejs/node-v10.11.0-linux-x64/bin/npx
Exec: true
Write: true
Read: true
/builds/myuser/myproj/.gradle/nodejs/node-v10.11.0-linux-x64/bin/node
Exec: true
Write: true
Read: true
/builds/myuser/myproj/.gradle/nodejs/node-v10.11.0-linux-x64/bin/npm
Exec: true
Write: true
Read: true
```

Also, it's in the PATH variable:

```
PATH=/builds/myuser/myproj/.gradle/nodejs/node-v10.11.0-linux-x64/bin:
```

Comment: Can you verify the content of this folder: `pwd`/.gradle/nodejs/node-v10.11.0-linux-x64/bin as well as if node's there and it works?

Comment: yes, it contains node, npm and npx and permissions on files are correctly set. I have added the output to the question.

Comment: @LiquidStudiosSeattle Did you find any solution to this problem. We are also bumping into this problem at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `gradle:alpine` image has problems working with node. I solved the problem by switching to the `gradle:slim` image; which works fine with node and the gradle node plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't working is because alpine uses musl and that requires a different node version, there are unofficial builds available for it, but the gradle plugin does not currently detect musl https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v13.0.1/

One way to get around this would be to use `download = false` conditionally and pre-install node in your CI env, but the easiest way is to just not use a docker image that uses musl.

There's an open issue in the fork for this https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin/issues/51

Answer (score 0):

According to https://hub.docker.com/_/gradle

> **gradle:<version>** This is the defacto image. If you are unsure about
> what your needs are, you probably want to use this one. It is designed
> to be used both as a throw away container (mount your source code and
> start the container to start your app), as well as the base to build
> other images off of.
>
> Some of these tags may have names like focal or jammy in them. These
> are the suite code names for releases of Ubuntu and indicate which
> release the image is based on. If your image needs to install any
> additional packages beyond what comes with the image, you'll likely
> want to specify one of these explicitly to minimize breakage when
> there are new releases of Ubuntu.
>
> **gradle:<version>-alpine** This image is based on the popular Alpine
> Linux project, available in the alpine official image. Alpine Linux is
> much smaller than most distribution base images (~5MB), and thus leads
> to much slimmer images in general.
>
> This variant is useful when final image size being as small as
> possible is your primary concern. The main caveat to note is that it
> does use musl libc instead of glibc and friends, so software will
> often run into issues depending on the depth of their libc
> requirements/assumptions. See this Hacker News comment thread for more
> discussion of the issues that might arise and some pro/con comparisons
> of using Alpine-based images.
>
> To minimize image size, it's uncommon for additional related tools
> (such as git or bash) to be included in Alpine-based images. Using
> this image as a base, add the things you need in your own Dockerfile
> (see the alpine image description for examples of how to install
> packages if you are unfamiliar).

I changed my Dockerfile from

`FROM gradle:7.6-alpine as builder`

to

`FROM gradle:7.6 as builder`

and the build was able to run the `node` binary.  There are also `-focal` and `-jammy` images (both also worked) but I chose to stay with the default since it won't be shipped anyway.  I couldn't find a `-slim` version.